# Time Efficiency of mergesort on linked list vs array of pointers

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to figure out the time efficiency of mergesort on a linked list versus an array of pointers (Not worrying about how I am going to use it in the future, solely the speed at which the data get sorted).

Which would be faster. I imagine using an array of pointers requires an additional layer of memory access.
But at the same time, accessing a linked list would be slower Assuming we go in already knowing the linked list length, mergesort would still require iterating through the linked list jumping from memory to memory til you get a pointer to the middle node of the linked list, which I think thinks more time than an array.

Does anyone have any insights? Is it more contextual to the data being sorted?

Comment: when you have such a question - implement both and compare. That would surely depend on your implementation rather than the "abstract" one.

Comment: The efficiency of implementation using an `array of pointers` should be compared with the efficiency of `linked list of pointers`. In any case, I really don't think the pointer access would become a bottleneck for any of the two data structures.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am trying to understand the difference in general, thus the abstractness. In terms of implementation, it is the standard merge sort algorithm on an array of pointers say *char[] versus a linked list struct with ( *char data; struct *next)

Comment: `it is the standard merge sort algorithm on an array of pointers` for the merge sort you don't *need* an extra array of pointers. (So you can omit these steps).

Comment: @wildplasser Please provide a reference showing how to do a merge sort of an array of pointers without using an extra array of pointers.

Comment: @JimMischel : I meant: you don't need the auxillary array. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47796391/905902

Comment: @wildplasser That's sorting a linked list. If you're sorting an *array* of pointers, you need the auxiliary array.

Comment: Srry, I misunderstood as "sorting a linked list using an auxillary array of pointers". Which is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference between implementing merge sort of a linked list versus an array of pointers is that with the array you end up having to use a secondary array. The algorithmic complexity is the same, O(n * log(n)) is the same, but the array version uses O(n) extra memory. You don't need to use that extra memory in the linked list case.

In real world implementation, runtime performance of the two should differ by a constant factor, but not enough to favor one over the other. That is, if you have an array of pointers, you probably won't benefit from turning it into a linked list, sorting, and converting it back to an array. Nor would you, given a linked list, benefit from creating an array, sorting it, and then building a new array.